# bind data source to Context Parameters in Web Performance Test using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, performance-testing, load-testing, webtest, context-param

I have a web performance test which tests an API. My API has **Context parameters** for which I would like to fetch values form database.  I can find how to fetch/bind values to Form Post parameters, but  **I need for Context Parameters**. Please help me in finding how to bind data source to Conext Paramters.

Example : my URI below

```
{{AppServer}}/test/{{DeptID}}/{{EmpID}}/Empinfo
```

AppServer, DeptID, EmpID are my context paramters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a list of values for a parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649732/how-to-use-a-list-of-values-for-a-parameter)

Comment: @AdrianHHH  -- As mentioned in my post I am looking for Context Parameters -- that link talks about/supports only Query String Paramters / Form Post Parameters... I am performing tests for API , in my question I posted my WEB API URI for which I can use only Context Parameters

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain what you actually want to do. Data source values are held as context parameters, so wanting *"to bind data source to Conext Paramters [sic]"* makes non sense. If you want to (eg) replace `{{AppServer}}` in the URI with a value from a data source then see the possible duplicate.

Comment: makes sense.. I can remove appserver from context parameters, but DEPTid AND eMPid have to be there as they change per request

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166840/visual-studio-load-performance-tests-parameterizing-rest-values-in-the-url?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer in this link : I need to remove context parameters and then directly bind the value in URI. [Visual Studio Load/Performance Tests - Parameterizing REST values in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166840/visual-studio-load-performance-tests-parameterizing-rest-values-in-the-url?rq=1)